# Iterating over $firebaseArray and $firebaseObject

Tags: firebase

I am trying to iterate over `firebaseObject` and `firebaseArray` fetched from my Firebase but they don't seem like normal javascript `objects` and `arrays`.

My data is stored in the following form

```
    'mainKey': {
      'key1':'value1',
      'key2':'value2'
   },
   'mainkey2': {
      'key3':'value3'
   }
```

I've tried the following code

```
   var firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<my-app>.firebaseio.com/);
    var fbArray = $firebaseArray(firebaseRef);
    var fbObject = $firebaseObject(firebaseRef);
    for(var i=0;i<fbArray.length;i++){
        console.log(fbArray[i]);
    }
   console.log(fbObject);
   console.log(fbObject.mainkey);
   console.log(fbArray.length);
```

This gives the following output in the console

```
Object { $$conf={...},  $id="test",  $priority=null,  more...} 

undefined

0
```

Though the object returned has `mainkey` property but I'm not able to access it.Why does this happen? And how should I iterate over them ?

Comment: There are libraries for working with Firebase and different languages, such as AngularFire for AngularJS and Firebase.  Even the documentation on Firebase indicates that the objects/arrays are not typical JavaScript.

Comment: I've checked Angularfire docs also but I couldn't find any soln in them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `for..in` loop to iterate over an object.
Below is an example:

```
for (var key in fbObject) {
  console.log(fbObject[key]); // You could use this method with all objects in JS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the info you need to know

> The $firebaseArray service takes a Firebase reference or Firebase Query and
>   returns a JavaScript array which contains the data at the provided Firebase 
>   reference. Note that the data will not be available immediately since 
>   retrieving it is an asynchronous operation. 
>   You can use the $loaded() promise to get notified when the data has loaded.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray

```
fbArray.$loaded(function() {
      //here you can iterate over your object
    });
```